# Image/Idea for 404 page

Tags: feature-request, 404-not-found

Many Stack Exchange sites have their own custom 404 pages with joke images, the most famous probably being the waffle iron on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/404) and Sean Connery in Zardoz on [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/404).

I had an idea that our 404 page could be a retro-looking terminal with something like "command not found" in the shell.  I was also inspired by `fortune|cowsay` and saw this in one of my terminal windows this evening:

[image: Terminal]

I don't know what the process is of requesting this 404 image to be implemented, but I figured I'd post here and see what other users thought.

Comment: I think this is part of the custom site design. I don't think I'll be able to convince the CM team to give us an early graduation in order to have one. It'll probably be 6 to 8 weeks after we graduate that we'll get a site design though; [codegolf.se] doesn't even have one yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like at some point in every beta site's life, someone asks this...

wizz's comment is correct. The custom 404 page is part of the custom site design you get when or if you graduate. It's never, to the best of my knowledge, been granted before that as a result of community request (or any other method, for that matter).

The time for posting suggestions for 404 pages will be when the designers arrive to solicit community ideas. That's likely to be a year or more away yet.